# Can we use HttpClient (SocketsHttpHandler) to get notified automatically like in case of TCP/IP when there is a new message in ActiveMQ?

Tags: c#, .net-core, activemq-classic, httplistener

I am working on an HTTP/HTTPS listener which basically listens to the ActiveMQ REST endpoint to get the latest messages. If we use a C# library like Apache.NMS then it's using TCP/IP to get notified about the new messages in ActiveMQ. I need the same notification/callback behavior while working with ActiveMQ REST endpoints.

Does anybody have any idea on how to constantly listen to ActiveMQ REST endpoint with some HTTP listener and get notified about new messages? I don't want to use polling (e.g. like calling the ActiveMQ REST API every 5-10 seconds).

Comment: No. That's not how HTTP works

Comment: Surely the best way to get notified when messages arrive is to use an ordinary message consumer? You not only get notified, but you actually get the messages ;) Is this about HTTP, or does your logic actually require notification so that you can take some action _other than_ consuming the messages?

Comment: No, my requirement is to get automatically notified when there is a new message in Active MQ just in case of NMS broker which uses TCP/IP, is that possible?

Comment: What do you do want to do when you get "notified", other than to consume the message? I don't really understand the usage scenario.

Comment: I just want to consume the message when there is a new message in the Active MQ but it should be with REST endpoint (HTTP/HTTPS)

Comment: you can't "consume" anything with HTTP. HTTP is a stateless request-response protocol. It doesn't maintain an open connection to anywhere - the client makes a request, the server responds, and then the process ends. It can't sit there listening. So you can set up a system which will regularly poll the queue for new messages but that isn't very efficient. I don't understand why you think you want to use HTTP for this.

Comment: All the comments and answers are telling you - repeatedly - that it's the wrong technology for your requirement, yet you continue asking for it as if it will somehow magically become possible if you ask enough times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ActiveMQ 5.x REST interface doesn't support callbacks of any sort so your only option is to poll. The reason an NMS client gets "notified" about messages is because that's the way it's written. It creates and holds a connection to the broker through which the broker can dispatch messages to it. HTTP just isn't suited to this task.

Generally speaking REST isn't a great solution for messaging specifically due to the lack of callback functionality. I'd recommend using something like STOMP which is simple and ubiquitous. Also, there is no standard for REST messaging. If you write your application to work with ActiveMQ 5.x's REST interface then your application will be tied to ActiveMQ 5.x. It won't work with any other broker. However, lots of brokers support STOMP.